# Can we fetch all the products using REST API without using limit

Tags: api, rest-api

I have found API calls for product listing like

```
http://xxxxxx.com/api/rest/products?limit=100
```

and

```
http://xxxxxx.com/api/rest/products
```

by default its 10 products and after passing limit its giving specific records, but can we get all the products without using `limit` and `page` params?

Answer (score 2):

It is not safe to remove limit completely, because your process will get out of memory and fail to return any products on real Magento store one day (when catalog grows to some extent). This is acceptable thing to do only during development for testing purposes.

Instead, pagination mechanisms provided by Magento (page and limit params) should be used to retrieve full catalog by chunks. Every chunk should ideally be processed by the client before requesting the next one to avoid memory issues on the client side. This is the only reliable approach.

Answer (score 2):

While it is not wise to do, yes, you can get all of the products in the system in one call.  All you have to do is send the query parameter **searchCriteria=0** but, you will need to be Admin Authenticated though.

You do it like this:

```
curl -X GET http://YOURMAGENTOURL/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria=0 -H 'Content-type: application/json' -H "Authorization: Bearer YOURAPIKEY"
```

Answer (score 0):

Please modify some code in file : Mage_Catalog_Model_Api2_Product_Rest

Go to this class and find the function `_retrieveCollection()` and update code as per below.

Updated code:

```
protected function _retrieveCollection()
{  
    /** @var $collection Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection */
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
    $store = $this->_getStore();
    $entityOnlyAttributes = $this->getEntityOnlyAttributes($this->getUserType(),
        Mage_Api2_Model_Resource::OPERATION_ATTRIBUTE_READ);
    $availableAttributes = array_keys($this->getAvailableAttributes($this->getUserType(),
        Mage_Api2_Model_Resource::OPERATION_ATTRIBUTE_READ));
    // available attributes not contain image attribute, but it needed for get image_url
    $availableAttributes[] = 'image';
    $collection->addStoreFilter($store->getId())
        ->addPriceData($this->_getCustomerGroupId(), $store->getWebsiteId())
        ->addAttributeToSelect(array_diff($availableAttributes, $entityOnlyAttributes))
        ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', array(
            'neq' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE))
        ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED));
    $dftAll = $collection->getSize();
    $this->_applyCategoryFilter($collection);
    $this->_applyCollectionModifiers($collection);
    $pageSize = $this->getRequest()->getPageSize();
    if (null == $pageSize) {
        $collection->setPageSize($dftAll); 
    }
    $products = $collection->load();

    /** @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product */
    foreach ($products as $product) {
        $this->_setProduct($product);
        $this->_prepareProductForResponse($product);
    }
    return $products->toArray();
}
```

Comment: i am getting 404 error, how can i solve the issue, abc.com/api/rest/products?limit=2

Comment: Have you given permission admin side under the REST Roles for the gust user?

Comment: yes i did that.